# SQL multiple date checks in a grouping

Tags: sql, databricks-sql

I currently have a table with the following format

| customer | shop | order_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Peter | Nike | 2023-02-02 |
| John | Reebok | 2021-12-12 |
| Peter | Adidas | 2022-09-10 |
| Peter | Nike | 2022-08-12 |
| Peter | Nike | 2020-10-10 |

I'd like to create a SELECT query that would result in the following format:

| customer | shop | returnedLast30Days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Peter | Nike | YES |
| Peter | Adidas | No |
| John | Reebok | NO |

Where in the returnedLast30Days I'd like to have a boolean value, which would indicate if the customer had more than 1 order in the last 365 days and at least one order in the last 30 days.

The final result should indicate if the customer is a returning one for the specific shop.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: why is peters visit to adidas excluded?

Comment: @nbk correct, I'll edit it :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have databricks so sorry if it's somehow doesn't work but please check this code:

```
SELECT 
    customer
    , shop
    , CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM your_table yt2 WHERE 
        yt2.shop = yt1.shop
            AND yt2.customer= yt1.customer
            AND yt2.order_date > current_date() - 30
    ) THEN 'T' ELSE 'N' END returned_last_30_days
FROM 
    your_table yt1;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this :/ I also don't see the check for the order in the last year. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a roundabout way of doing this, but in my opinion quite readable.

First find the orders that match our criteria in a subquery.

Next left join the original orders table back with the results of this Subquery.

We join on customer and company. If there are no matching customer-company pairs, the left side of the table will result in null. If there is a match, it will take the first match closest to the top (because of this the dates are not trustworthy in the resulting joined table)

Make sure we select distinct so we are only getting unique pairs of Customer/Company.

If the right side of the join is null, that means there was no join and the customer had not shopped at that store in the last 30 days. We can use a simple case statement to turn that into a Y/N field.

```
WITH returnedLast30Days As (
  SELECT * FROM customer_orders co  WHERE 
  co.order_date >=  (CURRENT_DATE - 30) AND
  co.order_date >= (CURRENT_DATE - 365)
)
SELECT DISTINCT
  co.customer,
  co.company,
  CASE WHEN co.customer = rl.customer THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END  as returnedLast30Days
FROM customer_orders co
LEFT JOIN returnedLast30Days rl ON 
    rl.company = co.company AND
    rl.customer = co.customer
```

Check out the [DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oQvOyzYn) here